# How to get past MongoDB/PCRE “symbol lookup error” when upgrading from MongoDB 1.8 to 2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, centos, redhat

I’m doing some Ruby development on servers that I have inherited (aka: I never originally set up.) that haven’t been maintained in a while and noticed that the installed MongoDB version was 1.8 when a 2.4 series upgrade was available. Since the box is running a RedHat/CentOS variant that uses `yum` to install RPMs, I went ahead and do what I usually do to upgrade. First, stop the running MongoDB instance like this:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

And then upgrade the packages from the repo.

```
sudo yum install mongodb mongodb-server libmongodb
```

All went well including dependencies being installed as well. But when I went to restart MongoDB bia this command:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Nothing appeared to happen. Connections were dead. Checking the MongoDB log showed the following one sad error line:

> /usr/bin/mongod: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE

What the heck is that about? I saw [this question and answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872774/epel-mongodb-will-not-start-on-ec2-amazon-ami) that recommending rebuilding from the RPM source as well as other posts online that advise some variant of the same: Download source code to recompile or download the RPM directly from the MongoDB site. But all of those solutions seem to radical for what should be a simple package installer update? What could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Somewhat accidentally, but fairly certain this is the solution. The short answer? If you get that `/usr/bin/mongod: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE` then you should install `pcre` and `pcre-devel` from the repository like this:

```
sudo yum install pcre pcre-devel
```

Details on how I discovered this are basically, I was resigning myself to recompiling [from scratch as outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874149/117259). That is something I do not want to do unless there is a very good reason. But as the answerer states, before recompiling one should install the following compiler items and related libraries:

```
sudo yum install rpm-build redhat-rpm-config gcc gcc-c++ make yum install openssl-devel snappy-devel v8-devel boost-devel python-devel python-nose scons pcre-devel readline-devel libpcap-devel gperftools-devel
```

Okay, so I did that to lay down the groundwork for a source code rebuild. But also noticed in the install that `pcre` was being installed as it was apparently missing and required dependency for `pcre-devel`; this is key. As I was getting ready to recompile I just decided to attempt to start `mongod` again like this:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

And checked. Lo and behold, the MongoDB install was running again!  But why? [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21009548/117259) holds the clue:

> The error was caused by `libpcre` changing the signature of
>   `RE::Init()` to only take a `std::string`, rather than a `char*`. This
>   is fixed if you get a newer version of `libpcrecpp`, which adds the
>   old interface for backwards compat.

That answer also recommended recompiling from source, but now that made little sense since it was clear my MongoDB install was up and running again. So I ran `lsof` on the development box and saw this:

```
sudo lsof | grep pcre
    nginx       892   deploy  mem       REG              253,2              97140006 (deleted)/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (stat: No such file or directory)
    nginx       893   deploy  mem       REG              253,2              97140006 (deleted)/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (stat: No such file or directory)
    nginx      1369     root  mem       REG              253,2              97140006 (deleted)/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (stat: No such file or directory)
    mongod    26841  mongodb  mem       REG              253,2               1052673 /usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0 (path dev=0,53)
    mongod    26841  mongodb  mem       REG              253,2              97126735 /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (path dev=0,53)
    grep      28590   deploy  mem       REG              253,2              97126735 /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (path dev=0,53)
```

Note how the `mongod` user is loading `/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1`. That has to be it, right?

I confirmed this by jumping onto the partner/twin production box of this setup—where I did not upgrade MongoDB on yet—and ran the same `lsof` command and this was the result:

```
sudo lsof | grep pcre
    nginx       922          root  mem       REG              253,2              81795343 (deleted)/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (stat: No such file or directory)
    nginx       923        deploy  mem       REG              253,2              81795343 (deleted)/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (stat: No such file or directory)
    nginx       924        deploy  mem       REG              253,2              81795343 (deleted)/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (stat: No such file or directory)
    grep       8067        deploy  mem       REG              253,2              81791051 /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1 (path dev=0,61)
```

Note how in comparison there is 100% no instance of `mongod` loading `/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1`. So the solution to this issue was not to recompile from source—and thus dealing with the headaches of a no-RPM install—but rather just to install `pcre` from the repository.